# daysToLive limit for upload authentication token for Fortify

Tags: fortify

I have several projects that need to be scanned and have their fpr files uploaded to a 360 server.  The pom files for the projects include the Fortify SCA plugin for maven and use the same authToken.  The fpr files were being uploaded successfully for a while, but have failed recently. I receive and ‘Access Denied’ when I run the following command from the command line trying to list the projects the authtoken has access to:

```
fortifyclient listprojects –url <360_SERVER_URL> -authtoken <AUTH_TOKEN>
```

I know there is a daysToLive option that can be used during token generation in order to specify the number of days the token is valid for.  I think I read that the default is 30 days.  I would like (and have tried) to make the daysToLive large as to avoid the need to continuously generate a new token and update all of the project pom files.  So my question is:

Is there a maximum limit on the daysToLive option when generating a new authentication token?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each auth token is defined in `WEB-INF/internal/serviceContext.xml`.

Look for each `<bean id="uploadToken" class="com.fortify.manager.security.ws.AuthenticationTokenSpec">` section for the specification of the token.  You can even define your own token if you want, but you will have to re-create it every time you upgrade the Fortify SSC/360 software.

The property that you want to change for a long time to live is: `<property name="maxDaysToLive" value="90"/>`

Comment: I have added that this is actually a known bug in the product.